# Expanding / Recombining macro tuple

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to do something like the following with macros in C++:

```
#define ESC(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define f1(a,b,c) {a:b:c}
#define f2(ab,c) ( ESC ab,c )
#define f3(ab,c) f1( ESC f2( ab, c ) )

f2((myA,myB),myC) // RESULT: (myA,myB,myC)
f3((myA,myB),myC) // DESIRED RESULT: {myA:myB:myC}
```

In other words, I have a set of parameters that is wrapped by a tuple (ab) as well as an unwrapped parameter (c) and I need to pass these into another macro function that takes parameters (a,b,c).

The macro f2 above gives me (a,b,c) from (ab,c), but from there I'm not able to use the (a,b,c) tuple to call f1. Clearly I'm approaching the problem incorrectly. Can someone point me to a better approach?

I am able to use BOOST_PP in this solution, if that makes things easier.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do some people like macros - usually end in tears when they use them

Comment: `a:b:c` is not valid C++ (it looks like the start of a bit-field but then some); why do you want that expansion?

Comment: a:b:c was just an example. The real point was to be able to call f1(a,b,c)... but the contents of that macro shown above are just a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define fst(first, second) first
#define snd(first, second) second
#define f3(ab,c) f1( fst ab, snd ab, c )
```

Comment: This approach works, thanks! Though BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM does the same job.